# proof of minimal element in natural integer subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

i'm currently looking for a way to prove the fact that there is a minimal element in every subset of the natural number set. I would like to have the proof inside the aximatic of ZF (without choice axiom), any idea ?

Thanks in advance, Bye !

Comment: Not sure why this got a -1 . . .

Comment: This questions need an improvement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define the natural numbers. The standard way is with the von Neumann construction: $0$ is the empty set, and $n + 1$ is $n \cup \{n\}$. So $1 = \{0\}$, $2 = \{0, 1\}$, and so on.

Using this definition, note that the Axiom of Regularity states that every set has a $\in$-minimal element. So any set of natural numbers has an element which is $\in$-minimal (so does not contain any of the other elements of the set). This will be your least element.

I can suggest more details if you like, but that ought to be enough to get you started.

Comment: yeah, i was asking about Von Neumann construction, but i never heard about ∈-minimal, what is it exactly ?

Comment: @toto $x$ is an $\in$-minimal element of a set $y$ if $x\in y$ but for no $z\in y$ do we have $z\in x$. That is, if we think of "$a\in b$" as meaning "$a$ is smaller than $b$" (which, while true in the context of ordinals, is usually nonsense), then an $\in$-minimal element of a set $y$ is an element $x$ of $y$ such that $y$ has no "smaller" elements.

Comment: So, i can say that using Von Neumann construction and the axiom of regularity implies that every subset of the natural set contains a minimal integer right ?

Comment: That's certainly true, but if you're using this for an assignment of any sort it won't be sufficient proof. You'll need to fill in the details.

Comment: Actually i'm studying math by myself, in order to improve my level in computation (i'm a developper). And i wanted to have a proof that stated that every subset of the natural numbers have a minimal element (because the induction theorem proof is based on the fact that every natural number subset have a minimal element, and i wanted a proof about that). But actually Reese, have you some paper or docs which go more further in this topic ?

Comment: Not specifically, but Kunen's set theory book should have a nice treatment of the Axiom of Regularity and von Neumann ordinals.

Comment: @Reese: FYI, current editions of Kunen's *Set Theory* no longer contain this elementary material; it's been moved into a separate volume entitled *The Foundations of Mathematics*.

Comment: That's great buddies. Thanks a lot !